# How to solve an error related to creating parser from regex?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, lexical-analysis

I am writing a parser using StandardTokenParsers in Scala. Need to create a regex parser to parse a path. I have tested the regex works fine but sending it to a function to parse it, the program gives an error that I am not able to figure it out! a part of code that is related to this parser is as follow:

```
 class InfixToPostfix extends StandardTokenParsers {
 import scala.util.matching.Regex
 import lexical.StringLit
//parsing the path
 def regexStringLit(r: Regex): Parser[String] =
 acceptMatch( "string literal matching regex " + r,{ case  StringLit(s) if r.unapplySeq(s).isDefined => s })
// Regex for path
 val pathIdent ="""/hdfs://[\d.]+:\d+/[\w/]+/\w+([.+]\w+)+""".r   
 def pathIdente: Parser[String] =regexStringLit(pathIdent)

 lexical.delimiters ++= List("+","-","*","/", "^","(",")",",")
 def value :Parser[Expr] = numericLit ^^ { s => Number(s) }
 def variable:Parser[Expr] =  pathIdente ^^ { s => Variable(s) }
 def parens:Parser[Expr] = "(" ~> expr <~ ")"

 def argument:Parser[Expr] = expr <~ (","?)
 def func:Parser[Expr] = ( pathIdente ~ "(" ~ (argument+) ~ ")" ^^ { case f ~ _ ~ e ~ _ => Function(f, e) })
//and the rest of the code ....
```

This parser is going to parse arithmetic operations. I use args(0) to send my input to the program which is : 
"/hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d+1"

and I get the following error:

```
[1.1] failure: string literal matching regex /hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+)) expected

 /hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d
 ^
```

Couldn't figure out how to solve it!

FYI: The part for "+1" is going to handle by the parser in the code so the part "pathIdent" is only for the path and that is the part causing the trouble. This is also good :

```
  """/hdfs://\d+(\.\d+){3}:\d+(/(\w+([.+]\w+)*))+""".r
```

it works fine outside of the code checking it in : regexpal.com
but still same error using it inside the program.

I am wondering if StringLit is the one that doesn't contain some of the characters and causing the error. Is there anything else other than StringLit that I can use here?

Comment: I think it says the input didn't match that regex. What was the input ?

Comment: for instance :  "/hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d+1" but I have commented the rest of the code except the path part and tried it with only  "/hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d" it still gives the same error

Comment: Where did this `/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))` come from? I only see `/hdfs://[\d.]+:\d+/[\w/]+/\w+([.+]\w+)+` in the code.

Comment: I didn't change anything in here, but I explained the other solutions I tried for regex like this: /hdfs://\d+(\.\d+){3}:\d+(/(\w+([.+]\w+)*))+

Comment: The only expression that doesn't match this `/hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d+1` input is `/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))`, all your other expressions match that input. Can you actually tell it what expression to use? If you can post the output showing that expression failing to match.

Comment: The part for "+1" is going to handle by the StandardTokenParsers in the code so this part (pathIdent) is only for the path and that is the part causing the trouble. This is also good : " /hdfs://\d+(\.\d+){3}:\d+(/(\w+([.+]\w+)*))+ " it works fine outside of the code checking it in : http://regexpal.com/ infact let me add this info to the question.

Comment: Then the basic conclusion is that the parser is not tearing off the delimiter `+`1 part before handing it to the `pathIdent`. But, why doesn't it show the string its matching against?

Comment: yes that is the actual problem that I can't understand. Because I tried it changing the regext to : """/hdfs://""".r and send "/hdfs://" as input and commented the rest of the code to see whether it can parse it or not. and I got the SAME error! I know something is missing but what is missing I can't undersstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure to match will be because the matcher is greedy. This is a common problem with regular expression matching (and hence lexical analysis) in several languages.

The greedy matching catches you at the end of the expression.

You have `([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))` but this will fail to match because the *word* `p` matched by the `\w` represented by the input text `folder1/p` is swallowed up by the piece `([\w/]+`. It stops at the period `.`. There is therefore no word before the dot to permit `(\w+\.\w+)` to ever match.

You'll have to rethink your regular expression and make each path fragment terminate at a solidus `/` rather than make it part of a set.

Do you see?

To make this work you need to express in the following way:

```
"""/hdfs://[\d.]+:\d+/(\w/)+\w+([.+]\w+)+""".r
```

Where I replaced `[\w/]+/`  by `(\w/)+`. This now specifies the ordering of the words and slashes and leaves a word unmatched for the following pattern to succeed.

Comment: Aha! I see what you are saying! So you mean to solve it I should separate the file name that contains dot?

Comment: I have tried this as well """/hdfs://\d+(\.\d+){3}:\d+(/(\w+([.+]\w+)*))+""".r but not working

Comment: I also changed my regex to be only: """/hdfs://""" and sent "/hdfs://" as input to the program and got the same error!

Comment: I am wondering if StringLit is the one that doesn't contain some of the characters and causing the error. Is there anything else other than StringLit that I can use here?

Comment: @Rubbic - I added more solution to my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you I am sure it'll work if the whole program works! you are helping me on this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30927074/3827280 I have put the whole program there , changed it in a way just to parse a string but it's not!